# Why is generating pdb file causing static linked library to increase largely in size?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While building small application (LZO) I noticed that the release build did not produce a pdb file. We usually tend to generated (but not necessary deploy) pdb files along with the libs itself.

Now I used the `/Zi` switch to turn on pdb file and notice one oddity. The pdb file was generated fine with ~100kb but the static linker lib grew from 259 kb to 622 kb and I do not understand why.

[Here is a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651107/why-does-generating-pdb-files-increase-the-size-of-my-native-c-exe) discussion growth of **executables** but as I do not build a final executable there is no code not being optimized away (`/OPT:NOREF` switch).

I expected the pdb file to contain addresses of what part of the code belongs to source etc and of course I expected the lib file to contain the compiled path of the pdb location but reading the bigger lib with a hex editor revealed a large amount of visual studio paths, own include paths, etc being compiled into it. Plus some non text binary data.
Why is this in the lib itself and not in the pdb causing the lib to grow?

Comment: Is this a question out of curosity only or does it cause you a problem?

Comment: @RogerRowland no issues, it just does not align with my current understanding of the lib file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the static library grows is because the fully qualified path name of the PDB file is associated with each object file in the .lib file.

So if your PDB filename is 30 characters long and you have 100 object files in the .lib you will get at least 3000 bytes added to the overall file size.

This is not an issue for .DLL or .EXE file as they only contain one reference the PDB filename.